# Комментарии HTML и PHP

Tags: php, html

```
<!--<input type="text" name="nomer_skan" id="nomer_skan" value="<?php echo $_POST['nomer_skan']; ?>"  />-->
```

В этом коде будет работать PHP скрипт? Или PHP скрипт требуется отдельно комментировать?

И это все зависит от настройки Сервера?

Comment: А проверить? PHP сработает

Comment: Проверял. Просто интересно это зависит от настроек сервера или нет

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Конечно будет работать. `HTML` разметка никак не влияет на `PHP`. Вы использовали комментарий только в разметке `HTML`, а это означает игнорирование браузером этого куска разметки. На `PHP` влияет только символы внутри тегов `<?php ?>`